# How to parse POJO with polymorphic field which contains JSON as String?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "type":"concrete",
    "poly":"{\"value\":\"CONCRETE VALUE\"}"
 }
```

As you see "poly" field is a JSON. And its a polymorph

And I have that POJO`s.

```
class Data(
        @JsonTypeId
        val type: String,
        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
        val poly: Base
)

@JsonSubTypes(
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Concrete::class, name = "concrete"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AnotherConcrete::class, name = "another")
)
interface Base

@JsonTypeName("concrete")
data class Concrete(val value: String) : Base


@JsonTypeName("another")
data class AnotherConcrete(val anotherValue: String) : Base
```

But when I try read value through object mapper, throws error

> InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of Base

Comment: Seems to work.. Can you post your JSON and the objectmapper code as well?

Comment: Also, why do you have quotation marks around your object braces and have the inner quotation marks escaped?

Comment: @sfiss  I have quotation marks around object braces becouse thats return from server api. Object mapper test code `kotlin
    @Test
    fun polymorphicField() {
        val json = """
            {
            "type":"concrete",
            "poly":"{\"value\":\"CONCRETE VALUE\"}"
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        val data = objectMapper.readValue<Data>(json, Data::class.java)
        Assert.assertTrue(data.poly is Concrete)
    }`

Comment: field "poly" its a raw json object as string

Comment: Maybee I can using custom deserializer for "poly" field but how I can get type inside deserializer?

Comment: You could use a static method annotated with `@JsonCreator` in your concrete data classes that accepts the object and parse the string yourself (or clean up the received JSON to not have this string literal and use the object mapper on that)